# Application runs but not really installed on my connected Android device

Tags: android, android-studio, deployment

I deployed my application (for test) on my connected Android device (with Android Studio 2.0 / Run - Lollilop for device).

My application runs correctly but it doesn't appear (physically) in the list of applications of my connected device.

Is it normal ?

I read when Android Studio deploys an application on connected device, it runs and installs the application.

Any ideas ?

Thanks you in advance

Comment: Yes the app is installed first and then launched. It is possible the app name got changed from label attribute defined in manifest. Check that and also the app icon in app list.

Comment: I verified several times: the application is not in the list of the applications ! i don't understand

Comment: What is that an application in debug mode cannot display in the list of the applications in production production ?

Comment: in fact my application is physically installed on my device (after verification) but when i try to open it, I obtain  a message "Impossible to execute"  - what can explain that my application does not appear in the list of the applications

Comment: Why my application does not run while android studio / run executes it with no problem at all ! it's very strange - any ideas ?

Comment: Make sure your main activity has an intent filter (in the AndroidManifest.xml) with a field: `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

Comment: Android studio execute my application with this command line : adb shell am start -n "com.fmaupin.cogito/com.fmaupin.cogito.Main2Activity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER - this is the current description of my main activity : <activity
            android:name=".Main2Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:exported="true"></activity>

Comment: if i update the android:name ("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER") for my main activity the run is crashed - i obtain this message : Error while executing: am start -n "com.fmaupin.cogito/com.fmaupin.cogito.Main2Activity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.fmaupin.cogito/.Main2Activity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.fmaupin.cogito/com.fmaupin.cogito.Main2Activity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity - Any ideas ?

Comment: I update my manifest.xml (correcty) :    <activity
            android:name=".Main2Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /></intent-filter>
        </activity> - no problem i am be able to launch my application now ! but my application doesn't appear in the list of my application !!! any ideas ?

Comment: My application appears in the list of the applications ok thanks you zmarkan for your help.